# Redirecting output to of a command to variable in Linux

Tags: linux, variables, command, redirect

Hello I tried saving output of command `grep -c ' language=\"*\"' sample_pos.xml` to variable `var1` like this but it is not working-

```
var=grep -c ' language=\"*\"' sample_pos.xml
```

Getting error:

```
./PVT.sh: line 2: -c: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Use command substitution:

```
  variable=`grep -c ' language=\"*\"' sample_pos.xml`
```

or

```
  variable=$(grep -c ' language=\"*\"' sample_pos.xml)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mithrandir.